# Parametrizing (all?) functions mapping onto [0, 1]

Tags: geometry, functions

I'm sorry if the question in the title isn't worded well or even properly. This stems from a personal project whose details I don't think are necessary here. But I will try and explain what I am looking for.

Basically, consider continuous $f : [ 0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$:

$$ f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n $$

such that $f_{max} = 1$ and $f_{min} = 0$ and $f$ is continuous. Now depending on parametrization $\{a_i\}$, I would like to obtain essentially all possible functions $f$ or maybe the family of functions $\{f\}$ that satisfy these conditions.

To add more, I have considered trig functions on the range but scaled in $x$ to fulfill this, a normalized gaussian with an offset would also work, and similarly an exponential function would do the job.

I realize all these can be described as $f$ above via taylor expansions, so a polynomial should be the most general description. What I imagine (and I might be wrong) is that there has to be a certain sets of parameters $a_i$ that give me the kind of function I want, and choosing one set or the other alters the shape in a distinct way, so what I am looking for is something that tells me what those sets of $a_i$ can be, or maybe a scheme for the coefficients. I would appreciate any and all help in this, including pointers to the fields of math I should look at. Coming from a physics background, I am not sure I would know where to look.

Again, if I can explain further or if there are questions regarding this, I would be happy to elaborate as best I can.

Comment: Are you looking for all continuous surjective functions or only for polynomials (which can approximate the others).

Comment: Yes, I think knowing all surjections would be ideal, but approximations would be good enough at this point. Since I am only testing out ideas currently, if I find problems in approximations itself, then I might abandon this approach entirely.